# The proper way to move the sections/navigation block inside Magento 2 header block

Tags: magento2

I'm attempting to move the entire navigation block within the page-header div inside Mage 2. I haven't found much documentation on specific block names so I have been guessing how to call each block. Below is what I have attempted.

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="top.links"/>
```

This moves the navigation links but leaves the section div. It also adds the element within top links which not what I'm trying to achieve. Using page.header as the destination fails to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the entire element including the sections div using the following.

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.panel"/>
```